# "Complex validation" with INotifyDataErrorInfo and MVVM (MVVMLight)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, inotifydataerrorinfo

Basically the problem is that I want to perform validation against some values that I get form a database (EF) before I execute the BL. I'm currently using INotifyDataErrorInfo with attributes in the properties of my ViewModel. I tried to do this validation with a custom validator (CustomValidation attribute):

```
        private string unit;
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = Constants.Error6)]
        [RegularExpression(Constants.AlphabeticRegEx, ErrorMessage = Constants.Error10)]
        [CustomValidation(typeof(ProductSelectionViewModel),"IsInRegisteredUnits")]
        public string Unit
        {
            get { return unit; }
            set
            {
                if (value == unit)
                    return;
                unit = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(vm => vm.Unit);
                UpdateUnitPrice(selectedProduct, unit);
            }
        }
```

But the method in charge of performing this validation must be a static one, so under this scenario I cannot acces to my repository since it is not static.

```
        public static ValidationResult IsInRegisteredUnits(object obj, ValidationContext context)
        {
            var productSelectionViewModel = (ProductSelectionViewModel)context.ObjectInstance;

            if (!unitService.GetAllUnitsAbbreviation().Any(x=>x.Equals(productSelectionViewModel.Unit, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
                return new ValidationResult("La unidad ingresada no es válida", new List<string> { "Unit" });
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
```

How can I solve this (unitService.GetAllUnitsAbbreviation() cannot be a static method since its using a repository), maybe I'm performing this kind of validation in the worng place (wrong design), any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: is "unitService" not available as a property/field of ProductSelectionViewModel?  That's how I call and validate through my services.